# How to check if particular data is present in CSV file or not in java?

Tags: java, database, file, csv

I have created a CSV file and put values by connecting with the database in java.

Now, I have to check if a particular data/ID is present in the CSV file or not? The CSV file contains multiple columns but I have to perform check on a single column of the CSV file.

Comment: Read each line. 
Put all the column values in an array ( Split by delimiter). You will know the column number(x) where you want to look. Look for that column data in the array(x+1)

Comment: Thank you so much @TrishulSinghChoudhary for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need a way to iterate the rows of your CSV file, then get the value in the column you want, and then compare that to the value you're searching for.

Fortunately there is an abundance of libraries that will simplify the handling of CVS files. Apache Commons has one that will read a file into an Iterable of CSVRecords. Check the docs [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html)

A function that does what you ask for could be:

```java
    public boolean columnContainsValue(String pathToFile, int columnIndex, String targetValue) throws IOException {

        Reader in = new FileReader(pathToFile);
        Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(in);

        for (CSVRecord record : records) {
            String rowValue = record.get(columnIndex);
            if (targetValue.equals(rowValue) )
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mtrycz for your solution. I am about to try this code but all of a sudden my requirement changed and not able to use this code.